# Ending a loop by sentinel and parsing an input string as an integer

Tags: c#, loops, sentinel

I am trying to continuously ask user for a number between 300-850. When the user enters a valid number, add it to the total and ask again. If the number is invalid, display an error. Before program ends, display the average of total number by amount of times of input. End program if user enters a sentinel value. I don't know how to check if user enters a sentinel value.

```
using System;

class CreditScores
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var iterations = 0;         
        double total = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        int count = 0; 

        Console.WriteLine("Enter value between 300 to 850.");
        int first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //trying to get it to stop when sentinel value reached.
        while (iterations < 1000)
        {
            iterations++;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter value between 300 to 850.");
            int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //not sure how to check if input is a number or not
            if(input == integer)
            {
                if( input < 850 && input > 300 )
                {
                    total +=input;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;  
            }

        }

        total = sum + total;
        Console.WriteLine("Total is {0}", total);

        average = total / count;
        Console.WriteLine("The average is {0}", average);
    }
}
```

Comment: `input` is always an integer (you define it as `int`), the `int.Parse` will fail with an exception if the number is not an integer.

Comment: What is the absolute goal? What should a user type to escape the loop? (I.e. `exit`, `calculate`, etc.) As it stands now they will be prompted for `1000` values, which would irritate even the most audacious user. I would just replace the `iterations < 1000` part with a different sentinel, that can be distinguished from an integer.

Answer (score 3):

## Modification/fix of Your Method

Also, I would read all the way to the end for the more robust method you could use.

First thing I would change:

```
while (iterations < 1000)
{
    ...
}
```

To this (which we are not done yet, read to the end):

```
while (input != "calculate") // or some other string
{
    ...
}
```

Then, before the `while` starts, make `input` a `string`.

```
string input = "";
while (input != "calculate") // or some other string
{
    ...
}
```

Now, we declared an `input` variable that is already an `int` later on. Let's fix that.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter value between 300 to 850.");
input = Console.ReadLine();
int value = 0;
if (int.TryParse(input, out value))
{
    // Clearly it's a valid integer at this point
    if (value < 850 && value > 300)
    {
        total += value;
    }
}
else
{
    // Wasn't a number, might be our sentinel.
    if (input == "calculate")
        break;  
    else
    {
        // Throw an error or something.
    }
}
```

Now, we need to put it together and do some cleaning.

```
int total = 0;
int numbersEntered = 0;
string input = "";

while (input != "calculate")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter value between 300 to 850.");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    int value = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(input, out value))
    {
        // Clearly it's a valid integer at this point
        if (value < 850 && value > 300)
        {
            total += value;
            numbersEntered++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Wasn't a number, might be our sentinel.
        if (input == "calculate")
            break;  
        else
        {
            // Throw an error or something.
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Total is {0}", total);

double average = (double)total / numbersEntered;
Console.WriteLine("The average is {0}", average);
```

(I know, long answer. But it should help you step through the problem in the future. Also, I wrote this all by memory, I can't guarantee it will compile.)

Update: just tested it, works as expected.

## A more Robust Method

Lastly, and this is really the coolest method in my opinion, use a `List<int>` and some extension methods.

```
List<int> values = new List<int>();

string input = "";
while (input != "calculate")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter value between 300 to 850.");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    int value = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(input, out value))
        // Clearly it's a valid integer at this point
        if (value < 850 && value > 300)
            values.Add(value);
        else
        {
            // Was outside our range
        }
    else
        // Wasn't a number, might be our sentinel.
        if (input == "calculate")
            break;
        else
        {
            // Throw an error or something.
        }
}

Console.WriteLine("Total is {0}", values.Sum());
Console.WriteLine("The average is {0}", values.Average());
```

Advantages to this method? It saves a list of the values entered, allowing you to do **more** with them that you cannot do with the method you currently have. It also uses the `int.Sum()` and `int.Average()` extension methods rather than your own math.

## What is this `int.TryParse(string, out int)` sorcery?

The `int.TryParse(string, out int)` method (as defined by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)) will take an input `string`, and return a boolean value that indicates if it would make a valid `int` structure or not.

In the case that the `string` is a valid `int`, then the `int` parameter is filled with the integer representation of the `string`.

I.e.:

```
string myString = "100";
int value = 0;
if (int.TryParse(myString, out value))
    Console.WriteLine("myString was a valid int: {0}", value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("myString was not a valid int.");
```

This version will return `true` and print: `myString was a valid int: 100`.

Example 2:

```
string myString = "blah";
int value = 0;
if (int.TryParse(myString, out value))
    Console.WriteLine("myString was a valid int: {0}", value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("myString was not a valid int.");
```

This version will return `false`, and print `myString was not a valid int.`. The `value` variable would also be `0`.

### Warning:

When using `int.TryParse(string input, out int value)`, do **not** rely on the `value` parameter as `0` to indicate failure. If the `input` is `"0"`, then the `value` will also be `0`, and the method will return `true`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you please explain the "TryParse" method?

Comment: @Addie123 The [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method takes an input string and an `out int` parameter, and returns a boolean that indicates whether or not the string is a valid `int`. If it is, then the `out int` parameter (`value`) in our case, is the `integer` value of the input string. I.e. `int.TryParse("100", out value);` would set `value` to `100`, and return `true`. Whereas `int.TryParse("blah", out value)` would return `false`, and `value` will be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the condition of your `while` loop to something that a user can trigger as false (the sentinel).
Then put a `for` loop inside that if you want to do a set number of iterations, for loops are better for situations where you know how many iterations you're doing.
BUT if you want to stick to while loops only, here's a quick code snippet you could use:

```
while (input != 0 && iterations < 1000) //or some sentinel value you choose
{
    //Your logic here, now the loop will quit if if the user enters 0 
    //OR you run out of iterations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
string sentinalValue = "done";
string input = "";
while (iterations < 1000 && input != sentinalValue)
{
    iterations++;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter value between 300 to 850.");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    int value;

    if (int.TryParse(input, out value))
    {
        if( value < 850 && value > 300 )
        {
            total +=input;
        }
    }

    else
    {
         Console.WriteLine("That is not a number!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Except the user has to enter 1000 tries to exit the program, or any invalid number.

Comment: Until the user enters a non-integer, and then it will break.

Comment: Not sure I agree, its 1000 tries or a **sentinal value** which I would guess means entering something like -1 or "quit", "exit", "done", etc. You don't want it to exit if they accidentally type in 200...

Comment: Yeah, I see. I though OP meant until the user enters a non string.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if(value < 850 && value > 300) ...`? and `total += value;`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
class CreditScores
{
    static void Main()
    {            
        double total = 0;
        int sum = 0;        
        int count = 0; 
        Console.WriteLine("Enter value between 300 to 850.");
        int first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //trying to get it to stop when sentihel value reached.
        for (iterations = 0; iterations < 1000; iterations++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter value between 300 to 850.");
            int input;
            // Check number is integer
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input)
            {
                if(input > 300 && input < 850)
                {
                    total +=input;
                }
            }    
            else
            {
                break;  
            }

            count++;
        }
        total = sum + total;
        Console.WriteLine("Total is {0}", total);

        double average = total/count;
        Console.WriteLine("The average is {0}", average);
        Console.ReadLine(); // Either this or run with Ctrl-F5
    }    
}
```

The behaviour would be to add the totals until the user entered something that couldn't be parsed, and then exit.